# Can GFR be improved in patients with kidney failure?

Tags: blood, blood-tests, biological-parameter, renal, glomerular-filtration-grf

How widely can glomerular filtration rate (GFR) values fluctuate and can they ever improve? How much "error" might one expect in the value if sampled quarterly?

Comment: Have you looked into this at all? For example, there are different causes of kidney failure, and some are reversible to a greater or lesser extent. What is the cause of the kidney failure you mention?

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been VTC'ed as too broad. I guess a simple "lowest and highest" acceptable value would suffice as an answer. As an example for blood-pressure: somewhere between 130/90 and 90/60 would be considered normal. *Can they ever improve* should maybe be edited out of the question.